# How to programmatically use certbot to enable/disable SSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, nginx, certbot

So I'm using nodejs and nginx and I want to use certbot programmatically with it and be able to get output from exec().

This command should generate the certificates without user interaction:

`certbot certonly --standalone --agree-tos -m my@email.com -d mydomain.com`

But I get lots of text and I only need the path to the certificates and the expiration date.

Is there a way to get that in a nodejs friendly format, like json?

Comment: You could instead use [Greenlock.js](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock.js)

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the man : https://certbot.eff.org/docs/man/certbot.html

Use the flag `-n Run non-interactively`

You can use the flag `nginx` to automate installation for this. 
`--nginx Obtain and install certificates using Nginx (default: False)`

Finaly : 
`certbot --agree-tos -n --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com -m hello@mail.com`